# Getting Empty dataframe when converting XML to dataframe

Tags: r, xml

I have an XML structure as follows (It is just a subset):

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Marketwired - Medical and Healthcare</title>
<link>http://www.marketwired.com</link>
<description>Marketwired - Medical and Healthcare</description>
<language>en</language>
<copyright>Copyright: (C) Marketwired</copyright>
<lastBuildDate>Tue, 11 Apr 2017 15:23:48 EDT</lastBuildDate>
<ttl>1</ttl>
<image>
<title>Marketwired.com</title>
<url>http://www.marketwired.com/rss/marketwire_logo.jpg</url>
<link>http://www.marketwired.com</link>
</image>
<item>
<title>
American Academy of Dermatology: Tips to Prevent and Treat Bug Bites
</title>
<link>
http://www.marketwired.com/mw/release.do?id=2209171&sourceType=3
</link>
<description>
<div class="mw_release"> <p>SCHAUMBURG, IL--(Marketwired - Apr 11, 2017) - Although warm, spring weather means more time outdoors, it also means more bugs -- like bees, ticks and mosquitoes. The best way to deal with pesky bites and stings, say dermatologists from the American Academy of Dermatology, is to prevent them in the first place. This can also help you avoid an insect-related disease, which can put a damper on anyone's spring.
</description>
<pubDate>Tue, 11 Apr 2017 14:00:00 EDT</pubDate>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

When I try to convert the above structure to a dataframe I get 0 rows and columns using the below line of code:

```
link <- "http://www.marketwire.com/rss/mwMedicalandHealthcare.xml"
xmlfeed<-xmlParse(link,asText=FALSE)
xmldata<-xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(xmlfeed,"rss/channel/item"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

So what could the issue be? I am trying to read the title and description under the item tag. You can view the entire XML file from the link mentioned above.

Comment: ```getNodeSet(xmlfeed,"/rss/channel")``` accesses the data, but probably not in the format you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially your xpath expression is slightly off as you need to lead with forward slash from root: `/rss/channel/item`. However, with your particular XML, even this fails to produce a dataframe due to the repeat `<category>` elements which will render duplicate column aliases.

Consider an `xpathSApply` approach to select the consistent elements such as *title* and *link*:

```
xmldata <- data.frame(
  title = xpathSApply(xmlfeed, "/rss/channel/item/title", xmlValue),
  link = xpathSApply(xmlfeed, "/rss/channel/item/link", xmlValue), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Now if you do really need each *category*, consider binding to *category1*, *category2*, *category3* fields by looping through number of *item* nodes. And specifically, use xpath's `concat` function to return a zero-length string if no such element exists:

```
no_items <- length(getNodeSet(xmlfeed,"/rss/channel/item"))

dfs <- lapply(seq(no_items), function(i){
  data.frame(
    title = xpathSApply(xmlfeed, paste0("/rss/channel/item[",i,"]/title"), xmlValue),
    link = xpathSApply(xmlfeed, paste0("/rss/channel/item[",i,"]/link"), xmlValue), 
    category1 = xpathSApply(xmlfeed, paste0("concat(/rss/channel/item[",i,"]/category[1], '')"), xmlValue), 
    category2= xpathSApply(xmlfeed, paste0("concat(/rss/channel/item[",i,"]/category[2], '')"), xmlValue), 
    category3= xpathSApply(xmlfeed, paste0("concat(/rss/channel/item[",i,"]/category[3], '')"), xmlValue), 
    category4= xpathSApply(xmlfeed, paste0("concat(/rss/channel/item[",i,"]/category[4], '')"), xmlValue), 
    category5= xpathSApply(xmlfeed, paste0("concat(/rss/channel/item[",i,"]/category[5], '')"), xmlValue), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )      
})

xmldata <- do.call(rbind, dfs)
```

**Output**

```
head(xmldf)                                                                                                                               

    # title
# 1 Morehouse Instrument Finds Perfect Balance Between Field Convenience And Laboratory Grade Precision with New Portable Force Calibrator
# 2          Cura-Can Health Corp. Secures Right to Acquire Assets of The Clinic Network Inc. and Acquires Assets of Healthnet Enterprises
# 3                                         Esterline Selects Jason Childs as President for Control & Communication Systems Business Group
# 4                                      ASAPS 2017 San Diego: Rosemont Media CEO to Lecture on Reputation Management for Plastic Surgeons
# 5                             Experts Discuss HIV/HCV Screening Program at Homestead Hospital on National Youth HIV & AIDS Awareness Day
# 6                                                                   American Academy of Dermatology: Tips to Prevent and Treat Bug Bites

#                                                               link category1 category2 category3 category4 category6
# 1 http://www.marketwired.com/mw/release.do?id=2209199&sourceType=3                                                  
# 2 http://www.marketwired.com/mw/release.do?id=2209198&sourceType=3                                                  
# 3 http://www.marketwired.com/mw/release.do?id=2209190&sourceType=3  NYSE:ESL                                        
# 4 http://www.marketwired.com/mw/release.do?id=2209184&sourceType=3                                                  
# 5 http://www.marketwired.com/mw/release.do?id=2209183&sourceType=3                                                  
# 6 http://www.marketwired.com/mw/release.do?id=2209171&sourceType=3
```